# TitleView disappears after program recovery

Tags: swift

I use DropDownMenuKit in the application. Using it I create

var titleView = DropDownTitleView ().
It works fine until you minimize the application.

The reaction on the iPhone is normal titleView is restored and it is visible. The reaction on the iPad when restoring the titleView disappears and pressing the drop-down field is processed and displayed, and the titleView is not visible.

Please tell me who knows what could be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use static variable:

```
struct Title{

 static var currentTitle : String = ""

}
```

and try so:

```
Title.currentTitle = "newTitle"
```